# how to kill a lightdm window without losing the session?

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm

My laptop was locked (showing lightdm unlock screen), and the battery went off overnight.

When I charged it up again there is the lightdm or gnome window asking me the session-end question "user, you have open files..." with the buttons to lock, sleep, restart, shutdown, and a close button on the top. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YxBS.jpg), but without mouse over highlights, and with my user unlock UI on the back. Also the top message  says

```
User, you have open files you might want to save. Would you like to..."
```

But I cannot click anywhere so I cannot get out of it. I tried going to the console, but the lightdm main process probably owns the window. I can't kill that one or i will lose the session. Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I killed a process owned by my user `/usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service --lockscreen-mode` I was then able to click the password field behind that screen, type unlock and then close that window.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your own answer after the delay of 2 days is over. Thank you! :-)